GitHub Actions workflow not triggering for Renovate app
I host my source code in GitHub. I use the hosted Renovate app to have dependencies updated automatically, which are merged into my main develop branch after a CI run succeeds.
I used to use Azure Pipelines for CI, and everything worked like a charm. I've recently migrated my CI flows over to GitHub Actions, but when Renovate opens a new pull request the CI workflow does not trigger.
My GitHub Actions workflow is as follows:
name: PR Verification

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop ]
    types: [ opened, synchronize, reopened, edited, ready_for_review ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '8.0.x'

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore

    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore

My primary branch is called develop.
When I open a new pull request myself, the workflow triggers. But when Renovate opens a pull request, it does not. How can I fix this?
What I've done:

Created a GitHub Actions workflow
Configured it to run on pull requests towards my develop branch

Expected:

GH Actions workflow to run when Renovate opens a pull request

Actual:

Workflow does not trigger


Is renovate using the default $GITHUB_TOKEN?  By default GitHub will disable workflows from being created if the triggerer is not a user to avoid an infinite loop of workflows

I use the Renovate GitHub app provided by Mend, which is installed as a GitHub app. It's my understanding that this uses its own tokens.

What's your Renovate setup? Is it configured to open PR or to auto merge if branch tests are successful? I mean you maybe want to enable your CI workflow on branch trigger as well.

I ended up figuring out the cause...
I originally used Azure DevOps, and had configured Renovate to put "[skip ci]" in commit messages. In AzDO, this causes the PR validation pipeline to run, but after merging to main the CI pipeline doesn't run.
In GitHub Actions, the presence of "[skip ci]" causes PR validation to get skipped altogether.
I've now removed "[skip ci]" from my Renovate config and changed the workflow so that the build step is not triggered when triggering_actor == "renovate[bot]"
